# Run exe from Jenkins on remote slave

Tags: jenkins, cmd, psexec

I have a Jenkins Master/Slave setup.
on Slave machine i have a testrun.exe in c:\temp

I need to execute this exe file in cmd.This exe takes 2 parameters
testsuite name and testcases file  name

In build step in Jenkins project I am using psexec:

PsExec -i -d \machinename -u machine\username -p password -accepteula  cmd /c  TestRunner.exe --tc Automation.xlsx --ts TestSuite.csv

jenkins output:

Connecting to ...

Starting PSEXESVC service on xx

Connecting with PsExec service on xx

Starting cmd on xx...

cmd started on xx with process ID 5096.

C:\temp\AthocENS\workspace\Cloud_Automation>exit 5096 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

When i login to remote machine i cannot see cmd window launched

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipeline or Windows batch build step?

Are you sure that you have escaped correctly all special characters in command line in case you are using Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Windows batch build step.

Comment: Have you tried to run this command manually on the machine? I see that you pass `-i` to the command which defaults to console session if no PID is specified. Also, `\machinename` should be `\\machinename`.